# Matlab insertObjectAnnotation labels error

Tags: matlab, text, label, matlab-cvst

I have this problem each time I try to display a text using
**insertObjectAnnotation** or **vision.TextInserter**
on a video in Matlab 2014b although the functions are defined in this version, does anyone knows what is the problem or how to fix that?

codes I tried
%Draw the objects on the frame and label it

```
blob = vision.BlobAnalysis('BoundingBoxOutputPort', true,...
        'MinimumBlobAreaSource', 'Property', 'MinimumBlobArea', 250);
frame  = step(videoSource);
[bboxes] = step(blob, frame);
labels = 'Object';
frame = insertObjectAnnotation(frame, 'rectangle', bboxes, labels);
```

also I tried those examples [here](http://mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/vision.textinserter-class.html)

> Error using matlab.system.StringSet/checkValues (line 127) The empty
>   string is not a valid StringSet string.
>
> Error in matlab.system.StringSet/setValues (line 113)
>
> Error in matlab.system.StringSet (line 31)
>
> Error in insertObjectAnnotation>getSystemObjects (line 539)
>       textInserter = vision.TextInserter( ...
>
> Error in insertObjectAnnotation (line 109) [textInserter, boxInserter,
>   cache] = getSystemObjects(shape, ...
>
> Error in distance (line 106)
>                      frame = insertObjectAnnotation(frame, 'rectangle',bboxes, labels);

Comment: Can you provide a working example that reproduces your problem?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `step()` method of `vision.BlobAnalysis` returns 3 outputs: areas, centroids, and the bounding boxes. So, what you have to do is this:

```
[~, ~, bboxes] = step(blob, frame);
```